# How to set the chapter style in report class?

Tags: sectioning, chapters, titlesec

I want to set chapters to look like 'bigger' sections.

Now in the `report` class I have a style like:

> Chapter 1
>
> Introduction
>
> 1.1. Section

What I want to achieve is:

> 1. Introduction
>
> 1.1. Section

I don't want to change the document class.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could use the [titlesec](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package. For example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\thechapter}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Section}
\end{document}
```

[image: titlesec example]

The package documentation will tell you more. Type `texdoc titlesec` at the command prompt or follow the link to CTAN at the beginning of this answer.

Comment: And what with the dot after 1 in chapter?

Comment: @pixel: just write `\thechapter.` in the `\titleformat` definition. Similar for sections.

Comment: Ok. It worked. I've also did same in `report.cls` to add dot in ToC.

Comment: @pixel: Generally it's not a good idea to directly modify a class file, though it's a quick fix for now. I recommend to use `\renewcommand` within your document instead to redefine the respective macro. Other documents might base on `report.cls`, so you would change their layout as well, also your future report documents.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz It does not work, instead of that I got rid of all the numbers before chapters and sections. Do you know what might be the case?

Comment: @AmoghJoshi You could post this as a question instead of a comment to an answer.

Comment: I needed to put the \titleformat section after the \begin{document}.

Answer (score 2):

Use the KOMA-Script class

```
\documentclass[numbers=enddot]{scrreprt}
```

Comment: I don't want to change document class, as I've written in my question (this document is in it's final stage and I'm doing only small corrections).

Comment: ah ok, I let it be as an answer for others