# Different line space in LaTeX for body text and for footnotes

Tags: footnotes, line-spacing

Hello I have a LaTeX document and I want to set the space betwen the lines. Normally I would use `\linespread`, but this command will change also the space between lines of footnotes and I do not want that. So, is there any command that can change the space between lines of text, excluding the footnote text?

Answer (score 7):

It's generally not advisable to use `\linespread` to change line spacing for this reason. The normal way is to use the [`setspace`](http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace) package. This makes footnotes single spaced by default.   See also [this question.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/819/2693)

Comment: I was just going to write the same answer. The documentation of `setspace` exists only inside the `.sty` file, so here the three spacing macros available: `\singlespacing`, `\onehalfspacing` and `\doublespacing`. Just load the package and use them.

Comment: So was I. :-) @alban: For "custom" spacing use e.g. `\setstretch{1.2}`.

Comment: thank you, actually i am trying to install the package, mitex is not finding it. thanks angain

Comment: I hadn't remembered that.  It's kind of annoying for such a widely used package (especially here in the U.S. where theses are almost always required to be double spaced) has no simple documentation.

Comment: @Alan: Someone should just convert it to a DTX and upload it to CTAN. The license should give you the right.

Comment: @alban Really?  I would be very surprised if it was not part of MikTeX.  It's definitely part of TeXLive.

Comment: I download and install it manually and works fine, thanks all. by the way is there a way to set chapters title font size?

Comment: @alban use the `titlesec` package.  See [this question.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10326/2693)