# Title fontsize affects the fontsize of the content

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, fontsize

I change some of my titles fontsize, for instance, the first chapter and first appendix

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside,titlepage]{report}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,amsmath,amsfonts,mathrsfs,syntonly}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{color}
\linespread{1.4}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\title{\textbf{My Title}}
\author{John Smith\\[5pt]
University of XXX\\[15pt]}

\date{\today}



\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents


\chapter{\LARGE My first chapter}
Here is my first chapter


\chapter{My second chapter}
Here is my first chapter



\chapter{My third chapter}
Here is my first chapter



\appendix
\chapter{\LARGE The first appendix}
\end{document}
```

However, these commands affect my Table of Contents, this line of content also change the font size. Would anyone tell me how to avoid this?

I am using TeXnicCenter and MiKTeX distribution.

Comment: That's not what I would expect. Can you please ass a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem? It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Hi, i just upload the whole codes, the first chapter and first appendix are using different fontsize. And so affects the fontsize of the table of contents.

Comment: Ok, now I understand the problem. You shouldn't format headings that way. Instead, use the `\titleformat` from the `titlesec` package. See [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10332/21891).

Comment: Or at least, write `\chapter{{\LARGE My first chapter}}` (note the double braces), to contain the font change.

Comment: @RyanReich Not that (otherwise you'll get the wrong linespacing), and anyway putting font changes in `\chapter` (and also in `\title` in the MWE) is just the wrong thing to do.

Comment: @David I will just pretend that my comment was intended to bring forth your rebuttal :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the optional argument to avoid that font changes are used in the toc (and the header) too:

```
\chapter[My first chapter]{\LARGE My first chapter}
```

But you should really avoid such individual font size changes. It will look awful. All your chapter titles should use the same font size.