# Do I need titlesec or is fncychap enough for doing the following?

Tags: chapters, titlesec, fncychap

i would like to change the "chapter" style of the documentclass "report" to read something like

```
1. Introduction
```

in stead of

```
Chapter 1


Introduction
```

Can anyone help me with this? Do I need `titlesec` or is `fncychap` enough?

Kind regards

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Changing this is very simple with `titlesec`. But are you already *using* `fnchchap`independently? Perhaps you could post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows what you're doing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the chapter style in report class?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10326/how-to-set-the-chapter-style-in-report-class)

Comment: `fancychap` has predefined styles i think what you need is not part of them but with titlesec you can do this easy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `fancychap` you have limited styles. On the other hand `titlesec` can help you to design whatever you want. Further, if you use `fancychap`, you will be making the Italian `TeX` guru (aka egreg) unhappy (which I won't do) `;-)`

Here is a sample with `titlesec`. Adjust the lengths as you like.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge\thechapter.\hskip0.5em}
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{0pt}{40pt}
\titlespacing*{name=\chapter,numberless} {0pt}{0pt}{40pt}
\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \chapter{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

[image]