# How do I remove the word "chapter" from chapter titles in documentclass/style {Thesis}

Tags: titles, chapters, thesis

I would like to have the chapter number at chapter title on the same line, so instead of:

"chapter 1

chapter name"

I would like

"1 Chapter name"

or

"1. chapter name"

i'm using `\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{Thesis}` and i would like to keep that, so that i do not have to change the rest of my document.

thank you in advance!

Edit: i see the change needs to happen in the Thesis.cls i use, so here is the part of the code concerning the chapter title:

```
%%
%% This is file `Thesis.cls', based on 'ECSthesis.cls', by Steve R. Gunn
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%

%% Created by Steve R. Gunn, modified by Sunil Patel: www.sunilpatel.co.uk

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\lhead[\rm\thepage]{\fancyplain{}{\sl{\rightmark}}}

\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\sl{\leftmark}}]{\rm\thepage}

\chead{}\lfoot{}\rfoot{}\cfoot{}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\btypeout{\thechapter\space #1}\markboth{\@chapapp\ \thechapter\ #1}{\@chapapp\ \thechapter\ #1}}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{}

\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{}

\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else

\hbox{}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\newpage
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) See [How to set the chapter style in report class?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10326/how-to-set-the-chapter-style-in-report-class) for a possible solution to your problem.

Comment: `A4paper` is no documentclass, it's an option

Comment: Have you seen this? [Do I need titlesec or is fncychap enough for doing the following?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/238233)

Comment: There is a bunch of more or less `Thesis` class files on the 'market'. Too which one you want to apply such changes?

Comment: I use one based on the ECS Thesis style by Steve Gunn,
I am writing in a a template from sharelatex, so i don't understand by main document fully, sadly.

Comment: For now i'm using the answer from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238228/do-i-need-titlesec-or-is-fncychap-enough-for-doing-the-following/238233#238233 But if someone knows how to do it with \renewcommand{} it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: For those interested in the template: http://www.sunilpatel.co.uk/thesis-template/

Comment: Please do not edit class files.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer so it is better to make the edit by using fx. your code in the master than to edit the class file? I'm just trying to get it right :)

Comment: @EmilieValente: Generally spoken, it's better to keep the original class file and do patches in the main document (or in a separate package). Editing should happen only in rare cases, when the `.cls` file is completely rotten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In lack of a `Thesis.cls` I used `book.cls` and the `\@makechapterhead` for `\chapter` (not `\chapter*`!) and did some hacking in there.

```
\documentclass{book}
\newif\ifusedot 

\usedottrue % Enable 1. format

\newcommand{\UseDot}{%
\ifusedot
.%
\else
%
\fi
}

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \huge\bfseries\thechapter\UseDot\space\@chapapp  %Here is the line for 1. Chapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }
}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
%\mainmatter
\chapter{My super sophisticated chapter}

\usedotfalse % Disable for some reason to show the effect

\chapter{My other sophisticated chapter}



\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit**

Since `Thesis.cls` uses `\LoadClass{book}` this should work there too. [ECS Thesis](http://www.sunilpatel.co.uk/thesis-template)

Editing and removing the `\par\break` stuff from the `\@makechapterhead` macro and removing of explicit `\@chapapp` in there. (Redefining `\@chapapp` to `\relax` is perhaps another option, but not recommended)

```
\documentclass{Thesis}


\usepackage{blindtext}


\makeatletter

\newif\ifusedot

\usedottrue

\newcommand{\UseDot}{%
\ifusedot
.%
\else
%
\fi
}

\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \huge\bfseries\thechapter\UseDot\space 
       % \par\nobreak % Kick out the break after the Number. \chapapp` stuff
       % \vskip 20\p@ 
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \huge\bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }
}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
%\mainmatter
\chapter{My super sophisticated chapter}

\usedotfalse

\chapter{My other sophisticated chapter}



\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but the "my super sophisticated chapter" looks exactly like my chapters does now?

Comment: @EmilieValente: I switched the order of Chapter and number ;-)

Comment: @EmilieValente: I think, your are after the `Number Chapter Name` style without paragraph breaking? If so, see my edited answer

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, I think OP wants to get rid of the word `Chapter` altogether.

Comment: @EmilieValente: Why did you unaccept the answer? If something is wrong then leave a comment, please

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: I reaccepted, sorry! i'm having some trouble accessing a question i posted whitout logging in, and i have now lost access to it after logging in with the entered email...