# Can't number sections with titlesec

Tags: titlesec

I want to achieve simple numbering of sections using `titlesec`, something like this:

```
1. Chapter
1.1. Section
1.1.1. Subsection
```

I get the feeling that something is wrong configured in my latex environment or titlesec is broken.

I have followed [How to set the chapter style in report class?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10326/how-to-set-the-chapter-style-in-report-class) to achieve my goal but the result is that instead of:

```
Chapter 1
Chapter
Section
Subsection
```

I get:

```
Chapter
Section
Subsection
```

I have also tried to use `\titlelabel{\thetitle.\quad}` to achieve any kind of numbering but without success.

I use Texmaker to compile to .pdf. Here is my experimental piece of code:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{titlesec}

%\titleformat{\chapter}
%  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\thechapter.}{1em}{}
%\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}

%\titleformat{\section}
%  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\thesection.}{1em}{}

%\titlelabel{\thetitle.\quad}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}

\end{document}
```

Can anyone suggest me what might be wrong? A task like this should be rather simple.

Comment: Which `titlesec` do you use? If it is 2.10.1 then you have to update the package. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299969/43317

Answer (score 1):

using the documentation of `titlesec` :

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{titlesec}

%\titleformat{\chapter}
%  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\thechapter.}{1em}{}
%\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}

%\titleformat{\section}
%  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\thesection.}{1em}{}

%\titlelabel{\thetitle.\quad}

\titleformat{\section}[block]
{\Large\bfseries}%
{\thesection}
{5mm}
{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]
{\large\bfseries}%
{\thesubsection}
{5mm}
{}

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
{\Huge\bfseries}%
{\thechapter}
{5mm}
{}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]