# Change chapter caption style to section caption style

Tags: sectioning, chapters, report

`\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}` is the format of my document. Writing `\chapter{Chapter one}` will create a new chapter on a new page with a lot of white space above the caption. Writing `\section{Section one}` will create a small caption with little white space around it.

How can I override the style of `\chapter{}` with the style of `\section{}` so that they will look the same? And is the caption of the table of contents also defined as an unnumbered `\chapter{}` heading? I am asking because I want the caption of my table of contents (and my list of tables/figures/etc.) to look like a `\section{}` caption as well.

Comment: Why not switch to the `article` documentclass and replace `\chapter` by `\section` and `\section` by `\subsection` respectively?

Comment: I tried doing this but my table of contents became a mess because sections in the table of contents low look like chapters and it did not uniformly convert all my chapter headings to section headings. The best way to solve my problem would be to override the report chapter heading style with the report section heading style because it would uniformly solve the style problem throughout the whole document.

Comment: Maybe you can use the solution presented here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10332/134144

Comment: You could try `\makeatletter\let\l@chapter=\l@section\makeatother` (untested).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `memoir` class with the `article` option, instead of the `report` class. The option makes `\chapter`s behave as `\section`s, `section` as `subsection` etc.

```
% \documentclass[...]{report}
\documentclass[article,...]{memoir}
and what you have already
```